# Stop reload for ajax submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html of form is like this

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="func.php">
   <table> <!--- DATA HERE --> </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="set" /> 
</form>
```

I want to use javascript to post the data, my javascript is like this

```
$('#set').live('click', function () {
        $('.setForm').attr('action', '');
        var setData = $('.setForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'func.php',
            data: setData,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#status').fadeIn('500').text('Loading..');
            }
        });
    });
```

but i am getting an error i dont know what error it is, (It is not visible in console) i have Break on errors enabled in firebug which returns

```
(function(){var R=/((?:\((?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)+\)|\[(?:\[[^[\]]*\]|['"][^'"]*['"]|[^[\]'"]+)+\]|\\.|[^ >+~,(\[\\]+)+|[>+~])(\s*,\s*)?/g,L=0,H=Object.prototype.toString;var F=function(Y,U,ab,ac){ab=ab||[];U=U||document;if(U.nodeType!==1&&U.nodeType!==9){return[]}if(!Y||typeof Y!=="string"){return ab}var Z=[],W,af,ai,T,ad,V,X=true;R.lastIndex=0;while((W=R.exec(Y))!==null){Z.push(W[1]);if(W[2]){V=RegExp.rightContext;break}}if(Z.length>1&&M.exec(Y)){if(Z.length===2&&I.relative[Z[0]]){af=J(Z[0]+Z[1],U)}else{af=I.relative[Z[0]]?[U]:F(Z.shift(),U);while(Z.length){Y=Z.shift();if(I.relative[Y]){Y+=Z.shift()}af=J(Y,af)}}}else{var ae=ac?{expr:Z.pop(),set:E(ac)}:F.find(Z.pop(),Z.length===1&&U.parentNode?U.parentNode:U,Q(U));af=F.filter(ae.expr,ae.set);if(Z.length>0){ai=E(af)}else{X=false}while(Z.length){var ah=Z.pop(),ag=ah;if(!I.relative[ah]){ah=""}else{ag=Z.pop()}if(ag==null){ag=U}I.relative[ah](ai,ag,Q(U))}}if(!ai){ai=af}if(!ai){throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+(ah||Y)}if(H.call(ai)==="[object Array]"){if(!X){ab.push.apply(ab,ai)}else{if(U.nodeType===1){for(var aa=0;ai[aa]!=null;aa++){if(ai[aa]&&(ai[aa]===true||ai[aa].nodeType===1&&K(U,ai[aa]))){ab.push(af[aa])}}}else{for(var aa=0;ai[aa]!=null;aa++){if(ai[aa]&&ai[aa].nodeType===1){ab.push(af[aa])}}}}}else{E(ai,ab)}if(V){F(V,U,ab,ac);if(G){hasDuplicate=false;ab.sort(G);if(hasDuplicate){for(var aa=1;aa<ab.length;aa++){if(ab[aa]===ab[aa-1]){ab.splice(aa--,1)}}}}}return ab};F.matches=function(T,U){return F(T,null,null,U)};F.find=function(aa,T,ab){var Z,X;if(!aa){return[]}for(var W=0,V=I.order.length;W<V;W++){var Y=I.order[W],X;if((X=I.match[Y].exec(aa))){var U=RegExp.leftContext;if(U.substr(U.length-1)!=="\\"){X[1]=(X[1]||"").replace(/\\/g,"");Z=I.find[Y](X,T,ab);if(Z!=null){aa=aa.replace(I.match[Y],"");break}}}}if(!Z){Z=T.getElementsByTagName("*")}return{set:Z,expr:aa}};F.filter=function(ad,ac,ag,W){var V=ad,ai=[],aa=ac,Y,T,Z=ac&&ac[0]&&Q(ac[0]);while(ad&&ac.length){for(var ab in I.filter){if((Y=I.match[ab].exec(ad))!=null){var U=I.filter[ab],ah,af;T=false;if(aa==ai){ai=[]}if(I.preFilter[ab]){Y=I.preFilter[ab](Y,aa,ag,ai,W,Z);if(!Y){T=ah=true}else{if(Y===true){continue}}}if(Y){for(var X=0;(af=aa[X])!=null;X++){if(af){ah=U(af,Y,X,aa);var ae=W^!!ah;if(ag&&ah!=null){if(ae){T=true}else{aa[X]=false}}else{if(ae){ai.push(af);T=true}}}}}if(ah!==g){if(!ag){aa=ai}ad=ad.replace(I.match[ab],"");if(!T){return[]}break}}}if(ad==V){if(T==null){throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+ad}else{break}}V=ad}return aa};var I=F.selectors={order:["ID","NAME","TAG"],match:{ID:/#((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF_-]|\\.)+)/,CLASS:/\.((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF_-]|\\.)+)/,NAME:/\[name=['"]*((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF_-]|\\.)+)['"]*\]/,ATTR:/\[\s*((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF_-]|\\.)+)\s*(?:(\S?=)\s*(['"]*)(.*?)\3|)\s*\]/,TAG:/^((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF\*_-]|\\.)+)/,CHILD:/:(only|nth|last|first)-child(?:\((even|odd|[\dn+-]*)\))?/,POS:/:(nth|eq|gt|lt|first|last|even|odd)(?:\((\d*)\))?(?=[^-]|$)/,PSEUDO:/:((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF_-]|\\.)+)(?:\((['"]*)((?:\([^\)]+\)|[^\2\(\)]*)+)\2\))?/},attrMap:{"class":"className","for":"htmlFor"},attrHandle:{href:function(T){return T.getAttribute("href")}},relative:{"+":function(aa,T,Z){var X=typeof T==="string",ab=X&&!/\W/.test(T),Y=X&&!ab;if(ab&&!Z){T=T.toUpperCase()}for(var W=0,V=aa.length,U;W<V;W++){if((U=aa[W])){while((U=U.previousSibling)&&U.nodeType!==1){}aa[W]=Y||U&&U.nodeName===T?U||false:U===T}}if(Y){F.filter(T,aa,true)}},">":function(Z,U,aa){var X=typeof U==="string";if(X&&!/\W/.test(U)){U=aa?U:U.toUpperCase();for(var V=0,T=Z.length;V<T;V++){var Y=Z[V];if(Y){var W=Y.parentNode;Z[V]=W.nodeName===U?W:false}}}else{for(var V=0,T=Z.length;V<T;V++){var Y=Z[V];if(Y){Z[V]=X?Y.parentNode:Y.parentNode===U}}if(X){F.filter(U,Z,true)}}},"":function(W,U,Y){var V=L++,T=S;if(!U.match(/\W/)){var X=U=Y?U:U.toUpperCase();T=P}T("parentNode",U,V,W,X,Y)},"~":function(W,U,Y){var V=L++,T=S;if(typeof U==="string"&&!U.match(/\W/)){var X=U=Y?U:U.toUpperCase();T=P}T("previousSibling",U,V,W,X,Y)}},find:{ID:function(U,V,W){if(typeof V.getElementById!=="undefined"&&!W){var T=V.getElementById(U[1]);return T?[T]:[]}},NAME:function(V,Y,Z){if(typeof Y.getElementsByName!=="undefined"){var U=[],X=Y.getElementsByName(V[1]);for(var W=0,T=X.length;W<T;W++){if(X[W].getAttribute("name")===V[1]){U.push(X[W])}}return U.length===0?null:U}},TAG:function(T,U){return U.getElementsByTagName(T[1])}},preFilter:{CLASS:function(W,U,V,T,Z,aa){W=" "+W[1].replace(/\\/g,"")+" ";if(aa){return W}for(var X=0,Y;(Y=U[X])!=null;X++){if(Y){if(Z^(Y.className&&(" "+Y.className+" ").indexOf(W)>=0)){if(!V){T.push(Y)}}else{if(V){U[X]=false}}}}return false},ID:function(T){return T[1].replace(/\\/g,"")},TAG:function(U,T){for(var V=0;T[V]===false;V++){}return T[V]&&Q(T[V])?U[1]:U[1].toUpperCase()},CHILD:function(T){if(T[1]=="nth"){var U=/(-?)(\d*)n((?:\+|-)?\d*)/.exec(T[2]=="even"&&"2n"||T[2]=="odd"&&"2n+1"||!/\D/.test(T[2])&&"0n+"+T[2]||T[2]);T[2]=(U[1]+(U[2]||1))-0;T[3]=U[3]-0}T[0]=L++;return T},ATTR:function(X,U,V,T,Y,Z){var W=X[1].replace(/\\/g,"");if(!Z&&I.attrMap[W]){X[1]=I.attrMap[W]}if(X[2]==="~="){X[4]=" "+X[4]+" "}return X},PSEUDO:function(X,U,V,T,Y){if(X[1]==="not"){if(X[3].match(R).length>1||/^\w/.test(X[3])){X[3]=F(X[3],null,null,U)}else{var W=F.filter(X[3],U,V,true^Y);if(!V){T.push.apply(T,W)}return false}}else{if(I.match.POS.test(X[0])||I.match.CHILD.test(X[0])){return true}}return X},POS:function(T){T.unshift(true);return T}},filters:{enabled:function(T){return T.disabled===false&&T.type!=="hidden"},disabled:function(T){return T.disabled===true},checked:function(T){return T.checked===true},selected:function(T){T.parentNode.selectedIndex;return T.selected===true},parent:function(T){return !!T.firstChild},empty:function(T){return !T.firstChild},has:function(V,U,T){return !!F(T[3],V).length},header:function(T){return/h\d/i.test(T.nodeName)},text:function(T){return"text"===T.type},radio:function(T){return"radio"===T.type},checkbox:function(T){return"checkbox"===T.type},file:function(T){return"file"===T.type},password:function(T){return"password"===T.type},submit:function(T){return"submit"===T.type},image:function(T){return"image"===T.type},reset:function(T){return"reset"===T.type},button:function(T){return"button"===T.type||T.nodeName.toUpperCase()==="BUTTON"},input:function(T){return/input|select|textarea|button/i.test(T.nodeName)}},setFilters:{first:function(U,T){return T===0},last:function(V,U,T,W){return U===W.length-1},even:function(U,T){return T%2===0},odd:function(U,T){return T%2===1},lt:function(V,U,T){return U<T[3]-0},gt:function(V,U,T){return U>T[3]-0},nth:function(V,U,T){return T[3]-0==U},eq:function(V,U,T){return T[3]-0==U}},filter:{PSEUDO:function(Z,V,W,aa){var U=V[1],X=I.filters[U];if(X){return X(Z,W,V,aa)}else{if(U==="contains"){return(Z.textContent||Z.innerText||"").indexOf(V[3])>=0}else{if(U==="not"){var Y=V[3];for(var W=0,T=Y.length;W<T;W++){if(Y[W]===Z){return false}}return true}}}},CHILD:function(T,W){var Z=W[1],U=T;switch(Z){case"only":case"first":while(U=U.previousSibling){if(U.nodeType===1){return false}}if(Z=="first"){return true}U=T;case"last":while(U=U.nextSibling){if(U.nodeType===1){return false}}return true;case"nth":var V=W[2],ac=W[3];if(V==1&&ac==0){return true}var Y=W[0],ab=T.parentNode;if(ab&&(ab.sizcache!==Y||!T.nodeIndex)){var X=0;for(U=ab.firstChild;U;U=U.nextSibling){if(U.nodeType===1){U.nodeIndex=++X}}ab.sizcache=Y}var aa=T.nodeIndex-ac;if(V==0){return aa==0}else{return(aa%V==0&&aa/V>=0)}}},ID:function(U,T){return U.nodeType===1&&U.getAttribute("id")===T},TAG:function(U,T){return(T==="*"&&U.nodeType===1)||U.nodeName===T},CLASS:function(U,T){return(" "+(U.className||U.getAttribute("class"))+" ").indexOf(T)>-1},ATTR:function(Y,W){var V=W[1],T=I.attrHandle[V]?I.attrHandle[V](Y):Y[V]!=null?Y[V]:Y.getAttribute(V),Z=T+"",X=W[2],U=W[4];return T==null?X==="!=":X==="="?Z===U:X==="*="?Z.indexOf(U)>=0:X==="~="?(" "+Z+" ").indexOf(U)>=0:!U?Z&&T!==false:X==="!="?Z!=U:X==="^="?Z.indexOf(U)===0:X==="$="?Z.substr(Z.length-U.length)===U:X==="|="?Z===U||Z.substr(0,U.length+1)===U+"-":false},POS:function(X,U,V,Y){var T=U[2],W=I.setFilters[T];if(W){return W(X,V,U,Y)}}}};var M=I.match.POS;for(var O in I.match){I.match[O]=RegExp(I.match[O].source+/(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))/.source)}var E=function(U,T){U=Array.prototype.slice.call(U);if(T){T.push.apply(T,U);return T}return U};try{Array.prototype.slice.call(document.documentElement.childNodes)}catch(N){E=function(X,W){var U=W||[];if(H.call(X)==="[object Array]"){Array.prototype.push.apply(U,X)}else{if(typeof X.length==="number"){for(var V=0,T=X.length;V<T;V++){U.push(X[V])}}else{for(var V=0;X[V];V++){U.push(X[V])}}}return U}}var G;if(document.documentElement.compareDocumentPosition){G=function(U,T){var V=U.compareDocumentPosition(T)&4?-1:U===T?0:1;if(V===0){hasDuplicate=true}return V}}else{if("sourceIndex" in document.documentElement){G=function(U,T){var V=U.sourceIndex-T.sourceIndex;if(V===0){hasDuplicate=true}return V}}else{if(document.createRange){G=function(W,U){var V=W.ownerDocument.createRange(),T=U.ownerDocument.createRange();V.selectNode(W);V.collapse(true);T.selectNode(U);T.collapse(true);var X=V.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END,T);if(X===0){hasDuplicate=true}return X}}}}(function(){var U=document.createElement("form"),V="script"+(new Date).getTime();U.innerHTML="<input name='"+V+"'/>";var T=document.documentElement;T.insertBefore(U,T.firstChild);if(!!document.getElementById(V)){I.find.ID=function(X,Y,Z){if(typeof Y.getElementById!=="undefined"&&!Z){var W=Y.getElementById(X[1]);return W?W.id===X[1]||typeof W.getAttributeNode!=="undefined"&&W.getAttributeNode("id").nodeValue===X[1]?[W]:g:[]}};I.filter.ID=function(Y,W){var X=typeof Y.getAttributeNode!=="undefined"&&Y.getAttributeNode("id");return Y.nodeType===1&&X&&X.nodeValue===W}}T.removeChild(U)})();(function(){var T=document.createElement("div");T.appendChild(document.createComment(""));if(T.getElementsByTagName("*").length>0){I.find.TAG=function(U,Y){var X=Y.getElementsByTagName(U[1]);if(U[1]==="*"){var W=[];for(var V=0;X[V];V++){if(X[V].nodeType===1){W.push(X[V])}}X=W}return X}}T.innerHTML="<a href='#'></a>";if(T.firstChild&&typeof T.firstChild.getAttribute!=="undefined"&&T.firstChild.getAttribute("href")!=="#"){I.attrHandle.href=function(U){return U.getAttribute("href",2)}}})();if(document.querySelectorAll){(function(){var T=F,U=document.createElement("div");U.innerHTML="<p class='TEST'></p>";if(U.querySelectorAll&&U.querySelectorAll(".TEST").length===0){return}F=function(Y,X,V,W){X=X||document;if(!W&&X.nodeType===9&&!Q(X)){try{return E(X.querySelectorAll(Y),V)}catch(Z){}}return T(Y,X,V,W)};F.find=T.find;F.filter=T.filter;F.selectors=T.selectors;F.matches=T.matches})()}if(document.getElementsByClassName&&document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName){(function(){var T=document.createElement("div");T.innerHTML="<div class='test e'></div><div class='test'></div>";if(T.getElementsByClassName("e").length===0){return}T.lastChild.className="e";if(T.getElementsByClassName("e").length===1){return}I.order.splice(1,0,"CLASS");I.find.CLASS=function(U,V,W){if(typeof V.getElementsByClassName!=="undefined"&&!W){return V.getElementsByClassName(U[1])}}})()}function P(U,Z,Y,ad,aa,ac){var ab=U=="previousSibling"&&!ac;for(var W=0,V=ad.length;W<V;W++){var T=ad[W];if(T){if(ab&&T.nodeType===1){T.sizcache=Y;T.sizset=W}T=T[U];var X=false;while(T){if(T.sizcache===Y){X=ad[T.sizset];break}if(T.nodeType===1&&!ac){T.sizcache=Y;T.sizset=W}if(T.nodeName===Z){X=T;break}T=T[U]}ad[W]=X}}}function S(U,Z,Y,ad,aa,ac){var ab=U=="previousSibling"&&!ac;for(var W=0,V=ad.length;W<V;W++){var T=ad[W];if(T){if(ab&&T.nodeType===1){T.sizcache=Y;T.sizset=W}T=T[U];var X=false;while(T){if(T.sizcache===Y){X=ad[T.sizset];break}if(T.nodeType===1){if(!ac){T.sizcache=Y;T.sizset=W}if(typeof Z!=="string"){if(T===Z){X=true;break}}else{if(F.filter(Z,[T]).length>0){X=T;break}}}T=T[U]}ad[W]=X}}}var K=document.compareDocumentPosition?function(U,T){return U.compareDocumentPosition(T)&16}:function(U,T){return U!==T&&(U.contains?U.contains(T):true)};var Q=function(T){return T.nodeType===9&&T.documentElement.nodeName!=="HTML"||!!T.ownerDocument&&Q(T.ownerDocument)};var J=function(T,aa){var W=[],X="",Y,V=aa.nodeType?[aa]:aa;while((Y=I.match.PSEUDO.exec(T))){X+=Y[0];T=T.replace(I.match.PSEUDO,"")}T=I.relative[T]?T+"*":T;for(var Z=0,U=V.length;Z<U;Z++){F(T,V[Z],W)}return F.filter(X,W)};o.find=F;o.filter=F.filter;o.expr=F.selectors;o.expr[":"]=o.expr.filters;F.selectors.filters.hidden=function(T){return T.offsetWidth===0||T.offsetHeight===0};F.selectors.filters.visible=function(T){return T.offsetWidth>0||T.offsetHeight>0};F.selectors.filters.animated=function(T){return o.grep(o.timers,function(U){return T===U.elem}).length};o.multiFilter=function(V,T,U){if(U){V=":not("+V+")"}return F.matches(V,T)};o.dir=function(V,U){var T=[],W=V[U];while(W&&W!=document){if(W.nodeType==1){T.push(W)}W=W[U]}return T};o.nth=function(X,T,V,W){T=T||1;var U=0;for(;X;X=X[V]){if(X.nodeType==1&&++U==T){break}}return X};o.sibling=function(V,U){var T=[];for(;V;V=V.nextSibling){if(V.nodeType==1&&V!=U){T.push(V)}}return T};return;l.Sizzle=F})();o.event={add:function(I,F,H,K){if(I.nodeType==3||I.nodeType==8){return}if(I.setInterval&&I!=l){I=l}if(!H.guid){H.guid=this.guid++}if(K!==g){var G=H;H=this.proxy(G);H.data=K}var E=o.data(I,"events")||o.data(I,"events",{}),J=o.data(I,"handle")||o.data(I,"handle",function(){return typeof o!=="undefined"&&!o.event.triggered?o.event.handle.apply(arguments.callee.elem,arguments):g});J.elem=I;o.each(F.split(/\s+/),function(M,N){var O=N.split(".");N=O.shift();H.type=O.slice().sort().join(".");var L=E[N];if(o.event.specialAll[N]){o.event.specialAll[N].setup.call(I,K,O)}if(!L){L=E[N]={};if(!o.event.special[N]||o.event.special[N].setup.call(I,K,O)===false){if(I.addEventListener){I.addEventListener(N,J,false)}else{if(I.attachEvent){I.attachEvent("on"+N,J)}}}}L[H.guid]=H;o.event.global[N]=true});I=null},guid:1,global:{},remove:function(K,H,J){if(K.nodeType==3||K.nodeType==8){return}var G=o.data(K,"events"),F,E;if(G){if(H===g||(typeof H==="string"&&H.charAt(0)==".")){for(var I in G){this.remove(K,I+(H||""))}}else{if(H.type){J=H.handler;H=H.type}o.each(H.split(/\s+/),function(M,O){var Q=O.split(".");O=Q.shift();var N=RegExp("(^|\\.)"+Q.slice().sort().join(".*\\.")+"(\\.|$)");if(G[O]){if(J){delete G[O][J.guid]}else{for(var P in G[O]){if(N.test(G[O][P].type)){delete G[O][P]}}}if(o.event.specialAll[O]){o.event.specialAll[O].teardown.call(K,Q)}for(F in G[O]){break}if(!F){if(!o.event.special[O]||o.event.special[O].teardown.call(K,Q)===false){if(K.removeEventListener){K.removeEventListener(O,o.data(K,"handle"),false)}else{if(K.detachEvent){K.detachEvent("on"+O,o.data(K,"handle"))}}}F=null;delete G[O]}}})}for(F in G){break}if(!F){var L=o.data(K,"handle");if(L){L.elem=null}o.removeData(K,"events");o.removeData(K,"handle")}}},trigger:function(I,K,H,E){var G=I.type||I;if(!E){I=typeof I==="object"?I[h]?I:o.extend(o.Event(G),I):o.Event(G);if(G.indexOf("!")>=0){I.type=G=G.slice(0,-1);I.exclusive=true}if(!H){I.stopPropagation();if(this.global[G]){o.each(o.cache,function(){if(this.events&&this.events[G]){o.event.trigger(I,K,this.handle.elem)}})}}if(!H||H.nodeType==3||H.nodeType==8){return g}I.result=g;I.target=H;K=o.makeArray(K);K.unshift(I)}I.currentTarget=H;var J=o.data(H,"handle");if(J){J.apply(H,K)}if((!H[G]||(o.nodeName(H,"a")&&G=="click"))&&H["on"+G]&&H["on"+G].apply(H,K)===false){I.result=false}if(!E&&H[G]&&!I.isDefaultPrevented()&&!(o.nodeName(H,"a")&&G=="click")){this.triggered=true;try{H[G]()}catch(L){}}this.triggered=false;if(!I.isPropagationStopped()){var F=H.parentNode||H.ownerDocument;if(F){o.event.trigger(I,K,F,true)}}},handle:function(K){var J,E;K=arguments[0]=o.event.fix(K||l.event);K.currentTarget=this;var L=K.type.split(".");K.type=L.shift();J=!L.length&&!K.exclusive;var I=RegExp("(^|\\.)"+L.slice().sort().join(".*\\.")+"(\\.|$)");E=(o.data(this,"events")||{})[K.type];for(var G in E){var H=E[G];if(J||I.test(H.type)){K.handler=H;K.data=H.data;var F=H.apply(this,arguments);if(F!==g){K.result=F;if(F===false){K.preventDefault();K.stopPropagation()}}if(K.isImmediatePropagationStopped()){break}}}},props:"altKey attrChange attrName bubbles button cancelable charCode clientX clientY ctrlKey currentTarget data detail eventPhase fromElement handler keyCode metaKey newValue originalTarget pageX pageY prevValue relatedNode relatedTarget screenX screenY shiftKey srcElement target toElement view wheelDelta which".split(" "),fix:function(H){if(H[h]){return H}var F=H;H=o.Event(F);for(var G=this.props.length,J;G;){J=this.props[--G];H[J]=F[J]}if(!H.target){H.target=H.srcElement||document}if(H.target.nodeType==3){H.target=H.target.parentNode}if(!H.relatedTarget&&H.fromElement){H.relatedTarget=H.fromElement==H.target?H.toElement:H.fromElement}if(H.pageX==null&&H.clientX!=null){var I=document.documentElement,E=document.body;H.pageX=H.clientX+(I&&I.scrollLeft||E&&E.scrollLeft||0)-(I.clientLeft||0);H.pageY=H.clientY+(I&&I.scrollTop||E&&E.scrollTop||0)-(I.clientTop||0)}if(!H.which&&((H.charCode||H.charCode===0)?H.charCode:H.keyCode)){H.which=H.charCode||H.keyCode}if(!H.metaKey&&H.ctrlKey){H.metaKey=H.ctrlKey}if(!H.which&&H.button){H.which=(H.button&1?1:(H.button&2?3:(H.button&4?2:0)))}return H},proxy:function(F,E){E=E||function(){return F.apply(this,arguments)};E.guid=F.guid=F.guid||E.guid||this.guid++;return E},special:{ready:{setup:B,teardown:function(){}}},specialAll:{live:{setup:function(E,F){o.event.add(this,F[0],c)},teardown:function(G){if(G.length){var E=0,F=RegExp("(^|\\.)"+G[0]+"(\\.|$)");o.each((o.data(this,"events").live||{}),function(){if(F.test(this.type)){E++}});if(E<1){o.event.remove(this,G[0],c)}}}}}};o.Event=function(E){if(!this.preventDefault){return new o.Event(E)}if(E&&E.type){this.originalEvent=E;this.type=E.type}else{this.type=E}this.timeStamp=e();this[h]=true};function k(){return false}function u(){return true}o.Event.prototype={preventDefault:function(){this.isDefaultPrevented=u;var E=this.originalEvent;if(!E){return}if(E.preventDefault){E.preventDefault()}E.returnValue=false},stopPropagation:function(){this.isPropagationStopped=u;var E=this.originalEvent;if(!E){return}if(E.stopPropagation){E.stopPropagation()}E.cancelBubble=true},stopImmediatePropagation:function(){this.isImmediatePropagationStopped=u;this.stopPropagation()},isDefaultPrevented:k,isPropagationStopped:k,isImmediatePropagationStopped:k};var a=function(F){var E=F.relatedTarget;while(E&&E!=this){try{E=E.parentNode}catch(G){E=this}}if(E!=this){F.type=F.data;o.event.handle.apply(this,arguments)}};o.each({mouseover:"mouseenter",mouseout:"mouseleave"},function(F,E){o.event.special[E]={setup:function(){o.event.add(this,F,a,E)},teardown:function(){o.event.remove(this,F,a)}}});o.fn.extend({bind:function(F,G,E){return F=="unload"?this.one(F,G,E):this.each(function(){o.event.add(this,F,E||G,E&&G)})},one:function(G,H,F){var E=o.event.proxy(F||H,function(I){o(this).unbind(I,E);return(F||H).apply(this,arguments)});return this.each(function(){o.event.add(this,G,E,F&&H)})},unbind:function(F,E){return this.each(function(){o.event.remove(this,F,E)})},trigger:function(E,F){return this.each(function(){o.event.trigger(E,F,this)})},triggerHandler:function(E,G){if(this[0]){var F=o.Event(E);F.preventDefault();F.stopPropagation();o.event.trigger(F,G,this[0]);return F.result}},toggle:function(G){var E=arguments,F=1;while(F<E.length){o.event.proxy(G,E[F++])}return this.click(o.event.proxy(G,function(H){this.lastToggle=(this.lastToggle||0)%F;H.preventDefault();return E[this.lastToggle++].apply(this,arguments)||false}))},hover:function(E,F){return this.mouseenter(E).mouseleave(F)},ready:function(E){B();if(o.isReady){E.call(document,o)}else{o.readyList.push(E)}return this},live:function(G,F){var E=o.event.proxy(F);E.guid+=this.selector+G;o(document).bind(i(G,this.selector),this.selector,E);return this},die:function(F,E){o(document).unbind(i(F,this.selector),E?{guid:E.guid+this.selector+F}:null);return this}});function c(H){var E=RegExp("(^|\\.)"+H.type+"(\\.|$)"),G=true,F=[];o.each(o.data(this,"events").live||[],function(I,J){if(E.test(J.type)){var K=o(H.target).closest(J.data)[0];if(K){F.push({elem:K,fn:J})}}});F.sort(function(J,I){return o.data(J.elem,"closest")-o.data(I.elem,"closest")});o.each(F,function(){if(this.fn.call(this.elem,H,this.fn.data)===false){return(G=false)}});return G}function i(F,E){return["live",F,E.replace(/\./g,"`").replace(/ /g,"|")].join(".")}o.extend({isReady:false,readyList:[],ready:function(){if(!o.isReady){o.isReady=true;if(o.readyList){o.each(o.readyList,function(){this.call(document,o)});o.readyList=null}o(document).triggerHandler("ready")}}});var x=false;function B(){if(x){return}x=true;if(document.addEventListener){document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",arguments.callee,false);o.ready()},false)}else{if(document.attachEvent){document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){if(document.readyState==="complete"){document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange",arguments.callee);o.ready()}});if(document.documentElement.doScroll&&l==l.top){(function(){if(o.isReady){return}try{document.documentElement.doScroll("left")}catch(E){setTimeout(arguments.callee,0);return}o.ready()})()}}}o.event.add(l,"load",o.ready)}o.each(("blur,focus,load,resize,scroll,unload,click,dblclick,mousedown,mouseup,mousemove,mouseover,mouseout,mouseenter,mouseleave,change,select,submit,keydown,keypress,keyup,error").split(","),function(F,E){o.fn[E]=function(G){return G?this.bind(E,G):this.trigger(E)}});o(l).bind("unload",function(){for(var E in o.cache){if(E!=1&&o.cache[E].handle){o.event.remove(o.cache[E].handle.elem)}}});(function(){o.support={};var F=document.documentElement,G=document.createElement("script"),K=document.createElement("div"),J="script"+(new Date).getTime();K.style.display="none";K.innerHTML=' <link/><table></table><a href="/a" style="color:red;float:left;opacity:.5;">a</a><select><option>text</option></select><object><param/></object>';var H=K.getElementsByTagName("*"),E=K.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];if(!H||!H.length||!E){return}o.support={leadingWhitespace:K.firstChild.nodeType==3,tbody:!K.getElementsByTagName("tbody").length,objectAll:!!K.getElementsByTagName("object")[0].getElementsByTagName("*").length,htmlSerialize:!!K.getElementsByTagName("link").length,style:/red/.test(E.getAttribute("style")),hrefNormalized:E.getAttribute("href")==="/a",opacity:E.style.opacity==="0.5",cssFloat:!!E.style.cssFloat,scriptEval:false,noCloneEvent:true,boxModel:null};G.type="text/javascript";try{G.appendChild(document.createTextNode("window."+J+"=1;"))}catch(I){}F.insertBefore(G,F.firstChild);if(l[J]){o.support.scriptEval=true;delete l[J]}F.removeChild(G);if(K.attachEvent&&K.fireEvent){K.attachEvent("onclick",function(){o.support.noCloneEvent=false;K.detachEvent("onclick",arguments.callee)});K.cloneNode(true).fireEvent("onclick")}o(function(){var L=document.createElement("div");L.style.width=L.style.paddingLeft="1px";document.body.appendChild(L);o.boxModel=o.support.boxModel=L.offsetWidth===2;document.body.removeChild(L).style.display="none"})})();var w=o.support.cssFloat?"cssFloat":"styleFloat";o.props={"for":"htmlFor","class":"className","float":w,cssFloat:w,styleFloat:w,readonly:"readOnly",maxlength:"maxLength",cellspacing:"cellSpacing",rowspan:"rowSpan",tabindex:"tabIndex"};o.fn.extend({_load:o.fn.load,load:function(G,J,K){if(typeof G!=="string"){return this._load(G)}var I=G.indexOf(" ");if(I>=0){var E=G.slice(I,G.length);G=G.slice(0,I)}var H="GET";if(J){if(o.isFunction(J)){K=J;J=null}else{if(typeof J==="object"){J=o.param(J);H="POST"}}}var F=this;o.ajax({url:G,type:H,dataType:"html",data:J,complete:function(M,L){if(L=="success"||L=="notmodified"){F.html(E?o("<div/>").append(M.responseText.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g,"")).find(E):M.responseText)}if(K){F.each(K,[M.responseText,L,M])}}});return this},serialize:function(){return o.param(this.serializeArray())},serializeArray:function(){return this.map(function(){return this.elements?o.makeArray(this.elements):this}).filter(function(){return this.name&&!this.disabled&&(this.checked||/select|textarea/i.test(this.nodeName)||/text|hidden|password|search/i.test(this.type))}).map(function(E,F){var G=o(this).val();return G==null?null:o.isArray(G)?o.map(G,function(I,H){return{name:F.name,value:I}}):{name:F.name,value:G}}).get()}});o.each("ajaxStart,ajaxStop,ajaxComplete,ajaxError,ajaxSuccess,ajaxSend".split(","),function(E,F){o.fn[F]=function(G){return this.bind(F,G)}});var r=e();o.extend({get:function(E,G,H,F){if(o.isFunction(G)){H=G;G=null}return o.ajax({type:"GET",url:E,data:G,success:H,dataType:F})},getScript:function(E,F){return o.get(E,null,F,"script")},getJSON:function(E,F,G){return o.get(E,F,G,"json")},post:function(E,G,H,F){if(o.isFunction(G)){H=G;G={}}return o.ajax({type:"POST",url:E,data:G,success:H,dataType:F})},ajaxSetup:function(E){o.extend(o.ajaxSettings,E)},ajaxSettings:{url:location.href,global:true,type:"GET",contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",processData:true,async:true,xhr:function(){return l.ActiveXObject?new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"):new XMLHttpRequest()},accepts:{xml:"application/xml, text/xml",html:"text/html",script:"text/javascript, application/javascript",json:"application/json, text/javascript",text:"text/plain",_default:"*/*"}},lastModified:{},ajax:function(M){M=o.extend(true,M,o.extend(true,{},o.ajaxSettings,M));var W,F=/=\?(&|$)/g,R,V,G=M.type.toUpperCase();if(M.data&&M.processData&&typeof M.data!=="string"){M.data=o.param(M.data)}if(M.dataType=="jsonp"){if(G=="GET"){if(!M.url.match(F)){M.url+=(M.url.match(/\?/)?"&":"?")+(M.jsonp||"callback")+"=?"}}else{if(!M.data||!M.data.match(F)){M.data=(M.data?M.data+"&":"")+(M.jsonp||"callback")+"=?"}}M.dataType="json"}if(M.dataType=="json"&&(M.data&&M.data.match(F)||M.url.match(F))){W="jsonp"+r++;if(M.data){M.data=(M.data+"").replace(F,"="+W+"$1")}M.url=M.url.replace(F,"="+W+"$1");M.dataType="script";l[W]=function(X){V=X;I();L();l[W]=g;try{delete l[W]}catch(Y){}if(H){H.removeChild(T)}}}if(M.dataType=="script"&&M.cache==null){M.cache=false}if(M.cache===false&&G=="GET"){var E=e();var U=M.url.replace(/(\?|&)_=.*?(&|$)/,"$1_="+E+"$2");M.url=U+((U==M.url)?(M.url.match(/\?/)?"&":"?")+"_="+E:"")}if(M.data&&G=="GET"){M.url+=(M.url.match(/\?/)?"&":"?")+M.data;M.data=null}if(M.global&&!o.active++){o.event.trigger("ajaxStart")}var Q=/^(\w+:)?\/\/([^\/?#]+)/.exec(M.url);if(M.dataType=="script"&&G=="GET"&&Q&&(Q[1]&&Q[1]!=location.protocol||Q[2]!=location.host)){var H=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];var T=document.createElement("script");T.src=M.url;if(M.scriptCharset){T.charset=M.scriptCharset}if(!W){var O=false;T.onload=T.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!O&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState=="loaded"||this.readyState=="complete")){O=true;I();L();T.onload=T.onreadystatechange=null;H.removeChild(T)}}}H.appendChild(T);return g}var K=false;var J=M.xhr();if(M.username){J.open(G,M.url,M.async,M.username,M.password)}else{J.open(G,M.url,M.async)}try{if(M.data){J.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",M.contentType)}if(M.ifModified){J.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since",o.lastModified[M.url]||"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT")}J.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");J.setRequestHeader("Accept",M.dataType&&M.accepts[M.dataType]?M.accepts[M.dataType]+", */*":M.accepts._default)}catch(S){}if(M.beforeSend&&M.beforeSend(J,M)===false){if(M.global&&!--o.active){o.event.trigger("ajaxStop")}J.abort();return false}if(M.global){o.event.trigger("ajaxSend",[J,M])}var N=function(X){if(J.readyState==0){if(P){clearInterval(P);P=null;if(M.global&&!--o.active){o.event.trigger("ajaxStop")}}}else{if(!K&&J&&(J.readyState==4||X=="timeout")){K=true;if(P){clearInterval(P);P=null}R=X=="timeout"?"timeout":!o.httpSuccess(J)?"error":M.ifModified&&o.httpNotModified(J,M.url)?"notmodified":"success";if(R=="success"){try{V=o.httpData(J,M.dataType,M)}catch(Z){R="parsererror"}}if(R=="success"){var Y;try{Y=J.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")}catch(Z){}if(M.ifModified&&Y){o.lastModified[M.url]=Y}if(!W){I()}}else{o.handleError(M,J,R)}L();if(X){J.abort()}if(M.async){J=null}}}};if(M.async){var P=setInterval(N,13);if(M.timeout>0){setTimeout(function(){if(J&&!K){N("timeout")}},M.timeout)}}try{J.send(M.data)}catch(S){o.handleError(M,J,null,S)}if(!M.async){N()}function I(){if(M.success){M.success(V,R)}if(M.global){o.event.trigger("ajaxSuccess",[J,M])}}function L(){if(M.complete){M.complete(J,R)}if(M.global){o.event.trigger("ajaxComplete",[J,M])}if(M.global&&!--o.active){o.event.trigger("ajaxStop")}}return J},handleError:function(F,H,E,G){if(F.error){F.error(H,E,G)}if(F.global){o.event.trigger("ajaxError",[H,F,G])}},active:0,httpSuccess:function(F){try{return !F.status&&location.protocol=="file:"||(F.status>=200&&F.status<300)||F.status==304||F.status==1223}catch(E){}return false},httpNotModified:function(G,E){try{var H=G.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");return G.status==304||H==o.lastModified[E]}catch(F){}return false},httpData:function(J,H,G){var F=J.getResponseHeader("content-type"),E=H=="xml"||!H&&F&&F.indexOf("xml")>=0,I=E?J.responseXML:J.responseText;if(E&&I.documentElement.tagName=="parsererror"){throw"parsererror"}if(G&&G.dataFilter){I=G.d
```

Comment: anytime you see sizcache and sizset attributes as in your debug, it is symptomatic of your javascript code having and error which prevents the jquery sizzle engine from cleaning up after itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you are using live? It's not necessary if the HTML is already there when the page loads.

Anyhow, the proper way to stop the form submission if you are using AJAX is not to catch the button's click event, but the form's submit event. You can then cancel the form's default action and do your AJAX stuff. This is best for usability.

This would be appropriate for the HTML above:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            success: function(r) {
                //...
            }
        });
        return false; // prevent form from submitting
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to add

```
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropogation()
```

to your function attached to the click.

I don't see where `.setForm` is coming from either so you data is probably undefined.

Comment: The code snippet you posted doesn't have .setForm is why I ask.

Comment: The correct answer for me was a combination of @Paolo's and this one.